# Is the metronome the closest thing to a mechanical drum?

Tags: rhythm, drums, tempo, metronomes

I noticed there's a lot of drum machines out there, but they're all electrical. Is the metronome the closest thing to a mechanical drum? and by mechanical I mean, there's no batteries/electricity involved.

I noticed most metronomes sound the same. I'm wondering if there's a metronome that sounds more like a drum and can produce rhythm, but is still mechanical and somewhat portable.

Comment: Well, a [clockwork monkey](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+clockwork+monkey&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjl8SVlsXcAhViKcAKHQu7CRQQ_AUICigB&biw=1106&bih=1329) would be very close too ;-)

Comment: People make mechanical drum machines, but mostly what I've seen is one-offs by hobbyists.   I haven't seen anything like that from North American music distributors as a commercial product.  I found a few projects by searching for mechanical or analogue drum machine.

Answer (score 1):

Does a [tractor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbN-jO11vKg) count?  You don't need any electricity after having started a reasonably aged one.

Which boils down to the principal problem: you need an energy source.  Combustion engines like the one used here are not useful for indoor use.  If you use electricity for running a mechanism, using electronics saves a lot of mass and trouble even though loudpeakers cannot hold a candle to the effiency of musical instruments regarding converting energy to sound.  But they are much more universal.

Nevertheless, there are "mechanical orchestras" running on pneumatics controlled by piano-roll type programs.  You can run some of them on man power and/or some clockwork but they'll be a really hefty workout.

A metronome usually has more of a "wood block" kind of sound rather than drums with a concentrated peak of sound energy.  It's actually easy to wind up, but it doesn't actually run for all that long.

Comment: too bad someone hasn't come up with the same concept as a metronome, ie a wound up spring/pendulum, and just have different sounds.

Comment: @foreyez  you need to get out more :-) :-)  .  I bet you can find dozens, if not hundreds,  of Wind-up musical instruments, including percussion.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I searched there isn't. only thing that is mechanical that compares with a drum is a metronome. but if u know any drumetronomes please share a link. (please note that I have invented a word)